# Prototype on $(document).ajaxComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototype

Can't understand why ErrorHandler.prototype.errorsBasket after ajaxComplete got new value

```
var ErrorHandler = function() {
  var _this = this;
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    _this.errorsBasket.push([1]);
  });
};

ErrorHandler.prototype.errorsBasket = [];
ErrorHandler.prototype.errorsBasket1 = [];

var a = new ErrorHandler();
a.errorsBasket1 = [2];
$.get('/');

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  why ->> console.log(ErrorHandler.prototype.errorsBasket); // [Array[1]] 
  console.log(ErrorHandler.prototype.errorsBasket1); // []
});
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/nBXAY/1/

Comment: What do you mean by "get new value"? You set it as an array. Then you push the value 1 to it on `ajaxComplete`. That's exactly the output you're getting. What were you expecting to get?

Answer (score 0):

when doing this:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    _this.errorsBasket.push([1]);
});
```

You are changing the value of `ErrorHandler` object wich will change it for every `new ErrorHandler`.

When doing this :

```
var a = new ErrorHandler();
a.errorsBasket1 = [2];
```

You are assigning a new value to `a`, which mean that if you remove this line :

```
ErrorHandler.prototype.errorsBasket1 = [];
```

And do

```
a.errorsBasket1 = [2];
```

It will work but

```
a.errorsBasket1; //without a.errorsBasket1 = [2];
```

will be undefined.

However this :

```
console.log(a.errorsBasket1); //without a.errorsBasket1 = [2];
ErrorHandler.prototype.errorsBasket1 = [0];
console.log(a.errorsBasket1);
```

will give

```
undefined
[0]
```

while this:

```
console.log(a.errorsBasket1); //with a.errorsBasket1 = [2];
ErrorHandler.prototype.errorsBasket1 = [0];
console.log(a.errorsBasket1);
```

will give

```
[2]
[2]
```

In summary, `ErrorHandler.prototype.errorsBasket1 = [];` is just a way to assign a default value to an object.